# Which book in the Dune series has Paul describing his prescience like standing amongst dunes?

Tags: dune

Which Dune book has Paul explain how he sees the future with the metaphor of looking from peak to peak across a series of dunes, with the implication that he cannot see into the wells of the dunes?

Answer (score 8):

This is from [Dune Messiah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_Messiah); Alia and Paul have a conversation with Stilgar:

> **“Stilgar,” Alia said, fighting to hold him, “you stand in a valley
>   between dunes. I stand on the crest. I see where you do not see. And,
>   among other things, I see mountains which conceal the distances.”**
>
> *“There are things hidden from you,” Stilgar said. “This you’ve always
>   said.”*
>
> *“All power is limited,” Alia said.*
>
> *“And danger may come from behind the mountains,” Stilgar said.*
>
> *“It’s something on that order,” Alia said.*
>
> *Stilgar nodded, his gaze fastened on Paul’s face. “But whatever comes
>   from behind the mountains must cross the dunes.”*

You might also be thinking of the preface to "Arrakis Awakening" (from the original Dune novel)

> *"Muad‘Dib could indeed see the Future, but you must understand the
>   limits of this power. Think of sight. You have eyes, yet cannot see
>   without light. **If you are on the floor of a valley, you cannot see
>   beyond your valley**. Just so, Muad’Dib could not always choose to look
>   across the mysterious terrain.*" - — <sub><sup>from “Arrakis Awakening” by the Princess Irulan</sup></sub>